# CreateMutex with bInitialOwner=true seem to be acting weird

Tags: c, multithreading, winapi, mutex

I am really at a loss here.
i read the MSDN articles thoroughly but still cant figure out what is going on.
my problem is this: when running a few processes with the following code all is working:

```
HANDLE m = CreateMutex(NULL, FALSE, L"MyMutex");
char c[20] = "2print";
for(int iter = 0; iter<100; ++iter) {
    WaitForSingleObject(m,INFINITE);
    for(int i=0;i<(int)strlen(c);++i) {
           for(int j=0;j<10000;++j)
                 printf("%c",c[i]);
    }
    BOOL ok = ReleaseMutex(m);
}
CloseHandle(m);
```

that is, the different processes each printing at its own turn and releasing the mutex until all printing is done.

BUT changing the CreateMutex to: (bInitialOwner from FALSE to TRUE)

```
HANDLE m = CreateMutex(NULL, TRUE, L"MyMutex");
```

the first creator will not release the mutex! other processes are just sitting there.
what amazed me was, that by adding an additional releaseMutex, that is changing:

```
BOOL ok = ReleaseMutex(m);
```

into:

```
BOOL ok = ReleaseMutex(m);
ok = ReleaseMutex(m);
```

make it work!

i am really confused, why wouldnt the first creator release the mutex correctly?
i tried printing all the errors using GetLastError, and what i get seem reasonable, like ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS for the creators following the first one, which is just what i expect (MSDN says that in this situation the bInitialOwner  is simply ignored).

Comment: Setting `bInitialOwner` to `TRUE` doesn't make sense here since you lock it (`WaitForSingleObject`) right after it.

Comment: Plus you say you have read MSDN articles, but [CreateMutex function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682411(v=vs.85).aspx) documentation clearly states: *"However, to release its ownership, the thread must call ReleaseMutex once for each time that the mutex satisfied a wait."*

Comment: well yes, but its a little subtle, at least was to me, to grasp that calling a wait function on a previously owned mutex will take ownership again.

Comment: Yeah. I got it. It's not very intuitive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `bInitialOwner=TRUE`, the mutex creator automatically acquires the mutex. Then when you call `WaitForSingleObject`, it acquired the mutex *again*. Since win32 mutexes are recursive mutexes, you must release once for each time you acquired the mutex - so two `ReleaseMutex` calls are needed for the initial creator (however every other thread must only release once!)

You can avoid this by either not using `bInitialOwner`, or by skipping the `WaitForSingleObject` on the *first loop only* if any only if `GetLastError() != ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS`. You will need to call `SetLastError(0)` prior to `CreateMutex` to clear the error code if you choose the latter.

If you only need `bInitialOwner` for some kind of initial setup, it will simplify your code if you drop the mutex prior to entering the common loop. Otherwise, I would strongly recommend simply not using `bInitialOwner`, unless you have a compelling reason to do so.

Comment: oh...how simple it all looks now. i overlooked the "call releaseMutex for each time you took ownership" rule. thanks!